# When calling Windows API functions from C#, which source for signatures to trust: .NET Framework source code or PInvoke?

Tags: c#, winapi, interop, pinvoke, signatures

For example, this is from .NET Framework source file *UnsafeNativeMethods.cs*:

```
[DllImport(ExternDll.User32, ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, 
    [In, Out] ref NativeMethods.RECT rect);
```

and this is from PInvoke.Net:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hwnd, out RECT lpRect);
```

1. Which is the correct/best signature for this function? (only one of them has `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]`, or `[In, Out] ref`, etc.)
2. I've noticed that in .NET Framework source files many/most signatures have `ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto`, but on PInvoke they don't. Is this required?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They will both get the job done.  There's just more than one way to skin a pinvoke cat.  Specifically for this example:

- `ExactSpelling=true` is an optimization, it avoids having the pinvoke marshaller looking for the `GetWindowRectA` and `GetWindowRectW` versions.  They don't exist for this particular API function since it doesn't take a string argument.  Seeing an actual difference in run time would be a miracle.
- `CharSet=CharSet.Auto` is always a good idea since the default (Ansi) is so inefficient.  It just so happens to not make any difference here since the function doesn't take any string arguments.
- `[In, Out]`  is unnecessary because that's the default for a blittable type.  An expensive word that means that the pinvoke marshaller can directly pass a pointer to the managed memory, no conversion is required.  As efficient as possible.  Same idea as `CharSet` though, being explicit about it helps to create self-documenting code and to remember to deal with the unusual case.  Being able to only use `[In]` or `[Out]` can be a significant optimization, just not here since it is already optimized.  Fwiw, [Out] would have been the correct choice.
- `out` vs `ref`, same idea as above.  Using `out` is more correct since the API doesn't actually use any passed-in values inside the `RECT`.  It doesn't however make any difference at runtime since the JIT compiler always initializes a struct anyway.
- `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]` is unnecessary, it is the default marshaling for a Windows `BOOL`.  Not sure why pinvoke.net always includes it.

So in a nutshell, neither is perfect but they both will work.  Such are the hazards of pinvoke.

Comment: FxCop will complain if you don't explicitly state the marshalling type where it is ambiguous. That is the case for bool (since there is Win32 BOOL, C++ bool and VARIANT_BOOL) or for strings.